# jQuery Closest() isn't working

Tags: jquery, closest

Could someone please explain me why replacing the following

```
$('.post_title a').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".post_footer").toggleClass('footer_border')
});
```

with

```
$('.post_title a').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest(".post_footer").toggleClass('footer_border')
});
```

doesn't work??

Comment: Is `.post_footer` exists inside `.post_title a`? `.closest()` searches current item and its parents.

Comment: Probably because `.post_footer` is not an ancestor of `a`. If you'd post your HTML we could say more.

Comment: Please post your HTML.  ALL answers would have to be guesses or inferences about what your HTML must look like as that is what determines how you find other objects in the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). It states that:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   `.closest()` method searches through these elements and their ancestors
>   in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching
>   elements. The `.parents()` and .`closest()` methods are similar in that
>   they both traverse up the DOM tree.

Since the element you're looking for isn't an ancestor of your link, it won't work. To achieve what you need, you could use this instead:

```
$(this).parents().next('.post_footer').eq(0).toggleClass('footer_border');
```

Comment: That worked minitech!! Thanks a ton :)
Make a lot more sense now :)

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it really helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

`closest()` is used to find the closest direct parent of an element.

In your first example, you use `find()` to locate an element inside the parent of the current element. This is why `closest()` fails - `.post_footer` is not a direct parent of the current element.

If you could post the HTML structure of your code I could provide you with more detail on how to resolve this.

Comment: Why can't I paste in the HTML Code. It simply refuses to add comment without any message.

Comment: @XtaticUforia Edit your original question and add the HTML to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this...

```
$('.post_title a').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest(PARENT_OF_POST_FOOTER_SELECTOR)
        .find(".post_footer").toggleClass('footer_border')
});
```

This assumes you have defined PARENT_OF_POST_FOOTER_SELECTOR.